# Google-auth authentication in django when the user abnormally close the browser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, google-oauth

I am performing Google-auth authentication but when the user abnormally close the browser, it results in freezes the application.

```
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
       settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON, self.SCOPES,redirect_uri='show_courses')
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
```

HOW TO HANDLE THIS IF USER CLOSE THE BROWSER BEFORE COMPLETING AUTHENTICATION